# Facebook Friend Selector for sending personalized message to ONE friend

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I need to implement a folw like that:
- the user choose a friend in facebook
- the user cannot chose more than one friend.
- the app send a personalized message to the friend
Testing with the         FB.ui({method: 'apprequests', etc...
I see that is not possible to limit the number of friends to select and so I can't send a very personalized message.
I think the only thing is to implement an 'in app' friend selector on my own... but looking for a simpler solution.

thanks,
A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A use a jquery plug-in for presenting my own friend selectors.

http://mike.brevoort.com/2010/08/10/introducing-the-jquery-facebook-multi-friend-selector-plugin/index.html

Once a friend is selected, then you pass the friend ID in the app request so only the send dialog with no friend selector is presented. I use this in the someecards facebook app if you want to see it in action.

Comment: it is perfect ... unfortunately it doesn't work in IE. Any idea on that?

Comment: Did you try it or are you basing that on the author's disclaimer? IE9, and mostly IE8 are pretty close to rendering to standards.

Comment: I try and on IE9 I only see my profile images without any other block (i can't see the selector)

Answer (score 3):

You can limit the maximum number of invitations by using `max_recipients`.

Here is a sample:

```
FB.ui(
    {
        method: 'apprequests',
        message: 'My Great Request',
        max_recipients:1
    }
    , 
    requestCallback
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'SEND dialog' . It will help you send personal messages to a single friend..

It will land on their inbox. But in this dialog also you can choose multiple friends..

And another restriction is that this dialog is mainly used for personal 'sharing' , so the sharing link is necessary

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/